# Kubuntu 15.10: Reset display resolution from recovery command line

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, display-resolution

I recently upgraded the graphics card in my computer from a very basic ATI card to a pretty decent NVIDIA card.  This required that I install the NVIDIA drivers.
I completed this, and managed to get a working, booting machine.  The only minor problem was that the display stays blank during boot (where normally I would see a kubuntu logo).

A few reboots later I suddenly found that the login splash screen is no longer displayed, and the monitor shows an "out of resolution" complaint.

I can boot into recovery from GRUB and access the command line.
**How can I modify the screenmode and resolution from the command line?**

Comment: `xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 60` -s is resolution and r refresh rate *Not sure* if it will reset resolution permanently, for grub file `GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080"`

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried this and it doesn't work for me - I get a complaint "Can't open display".

Comment: tried `rm ~/.config/monitors.xml`  ? (after taking backup)

Comment: Well, that's currently a problem for me: $HOME is encrypted and usually it's decrypted and mounted during boot.  But, from the recovery console, it doesn't appear that $HOME has been decrypted.  If I could get into $HOME then at this stage I'd probably just back everything up off there and install the new LTS 16.04 version.

Comment: Every way I turn for a solution to try and get into my system is met with an obstacle that I can't resolve.  I've put myself in a bad position with this.  Fortunately, not too much will be lost from a complete reinstall and on this occasion that's the path of least resistance for me.  Thanks very much for taking the time to comment with advice, appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 reached the end of its support life and is therefore off topic here. Please upgrade to a supported release (i. e. 16.04).